# laravel using findOrFail for validate other record not id

Tags: php, laravel

I have table contain id, customer_id,..etc so findOrFail will work only for id so want to check customer_id record not id.
How can I check other record using **findOrFail** something like this

```
$post = Customer::findOrFail('customer_id',$request->customer_id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `firstOrFail()`, so you can do:

`Customer::whereCustomerId($request->customer_id)->firstOrFail();`

`findOrFail()` only works for the primary key `id` so you have to use `firstOrFail`.

Note that you could also write it as:

`Customer::where('customer_id', $request->customer_id)->firstOrFail();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use any column of a table

```
Customer::where('<any column>', <column value>)->firstOrFail();
```

Laravel example

```
$model = App\Flight::findOrFail(1);

$model = App\Flight::where('legs', '>', 100)->firstOrFail();
```